# Updating Speed of falling Sprites! Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-defined-functions, sprite

I have created a mini game within Python, where I have a fire Sprite and the bottom of the screen moving side to side and a cloud Sprite at the top of the screen dropping snowballs. The aim of the game is to catch the snowballs and stop them hitting the bottom of the screen, otherwise it is game over. I would like to add a feature where when the total score hits 500 (10 points for every snowball caught) the snowballs drop faster. I have attempted many didferent lines of code just feel like im placing code in the wrong section ect. Any Ideas ?

```
# Stop the Snowball game.
from livewires import games, color
import random

games.init(screen_width=640, screen_height=440, fps=50)

class Fire(games.Sprite):
    # Fire sprite controlled by the user.
    image=games.load_image("FireSprite.png")
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Creating the score and Initialising the fire object.
        super(Fire, self).__init__( image=Fire.image,
                                    x=games.mouse.x,
                                    bottom=games.screen.height)
        self.score=games.Text(  value=0, size=25, color=color.yellow,
                                top=5, right=games.screen.width - 10)
        games.screen.add(self.score)
        
        
    def update(self):
        # Move to Mouse.
        self.x = games.mouse.x 
        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width
        self.check_catch()
        
    def check_catch(self):
        # Check to see if the Snowball was caught.
        for Snowball in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.score.value += 10
            self.score.right = games.screen.width - 10
            Snowball.handle_caught()
            
            
class Snowball(games.Sprite):
    # A Snowball that falls from the Cloud.
    image=games.load_image("SnowBall.png")
    speed=2
    
    def __init__(self, x, y=70):
        # Initialising the Snowball Object.
        super(Snowball, self).__init__(image=Snowball.image,
                                        x=x, y=y,
                                        dy=Snowball.speed)
                                        
            
    def update(self):
        # Check if the edge of SnowBall 
        # has reached the bottom of screen.
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
            self.end_game()
            self.destroy()
            
    def handle_caught(self):
        # Destroy the snowball if caught.
        # to stop build up of sprites.
        self.destroy()
        
    def end_game(self):
        # End the game
        end_message=games.Message(  value="Game Over!", size=90,
                                    color=color.yellow,
                                    x=games.screen.width/2,
                                    y=games.screen.height/2,
                                    lifetime= 5 * games.screen.fps,
                                    after_death = games.screen.quit)
        games.screen.add(end_message)
        
class Cloud(games.Sprite):
    # A cloud sprite that drops the snowballs, while moving left to right.
    image=games.load_image("Cloud.png")
    
    def __init__(self, y=20, speed=3, odds_change=200):
        # Initialising the cloud object.
        super(Cloud, self).__init__(    image=Cloud.image,
                                        x=games.screen.width/2,
                                        y=y, dx=speed)
        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0
        
    def update(self):
        # Check if the direction should be reversed.
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        elif random.randrange(self.odds_change) == 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        self.check_drop()
        
        
    def check_drop(self):
        # Decrease countdown or drop Snowball and reset countdown.
        if self.time_til_drop > 0:
            self.time_til_drop -= 1
        else:
            new_snowball = Snowball(x=self.x)
            games.screen.add(new_snowball)
            # Setting Buffer to 20% of snowball height.
            self.time_til_drop = int(new_snowball.height * 1.2 / Snowball.speed) + 1
        
def main():
    # Starting the game.
    WinterSnow = games.load_image("WinterSnow.png")
    games.screen.background = WinterSnow
    
    the_cloud = Cloud()
    games.screen.add(the_cloud)
    
    the_fire = Fire()
    games.screen.add(the_fire)
    
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True
    
    games.screen.mainloop()
    
# Start the program.
main()
```

Comment: Have I just got to Define a speed_up funtion and call the function later on ??

Answer (score 0):

SO I found out that i needed to update the "def Check_catch(self):" function.

```
for Snowball in self.overlapping_sprites:
    self.score.value += 10
if (self.score.value/500).is_interger():
    Snowball.speed += 1
self.score.right = games.screen.width - 10
Snowball.handle_caught()
```